# New to LUA, i have question about my script

Tags: lua

Hello im new to LUA and in general new to scripting/coding
This is script what im talking about

```
print("Type a Number!")
repeat
input = io.read()
if input == "10" then 
    print("Ten")
elseif input == "7" then
        print("Seven")

elseif input == "1" then
    print("One!")
elseif input == "exit" or input == "Exit" then
    print("Exiting...")  
else
     print("incorrect")  
end
until input == "Exit" or input == "exit"
```

I kinda feel like there is too much elseif but I didn't want to print "incorrect" when i type exit or Exit so my solution was to add another elseif before else command. Can be this be more simplified or i can't do nothing with it and its good

And one more question why this is not working

```
num = 10
input = io.read()
If input == num then 
     print("Ten")
end
```

Or this code

```
num = 10
input = io.read()
If input == 10 then 
     print("Ten")
end
```

Why code above where i have boolean with string after if, only works

Comment: 1) `If` is not the same as `if`.  2) `10` is not the same as `"10"` 3) `io.read()` returns string, you need `tonumber()` to convert it to number before comparing with another number

Answer (score 4):

1. Define your behaviour

```lua
local actions = {
   [1] = function() print("One");
   -- Same for any other numbers you want
   ["exit"] = function() os.exit() end; -- Close the whole program
}
```

2. Get your input

```lua
local input = io.read() -- This returns a string
```

3. Normalize your input

```lua
input = input:lower() -- Make the whole string lowercase
input = tonumber(input) or input -- Try converting to number
```

4. Get the action matching your input

```lua
local action = actions[input]
```

5. Run the action if one was found

```lua
if action then
   action()
else
   print("Error! Could not handle input: ", input)
end
```

Comment: oh actually make sense that the other 2 exemples of code did not worked, I didn't know that io.read() is only for strings...Is there similar type for numbers or i always have to convert it to number ? Thanks for answers very helpful :))))

Answer (score 3):

```lua
local inputs = {
     ['1'] = 'One!'
  ,  ['7'] = 'Seven'
  , ['10'] = 'Ten'
  , exit   = 'Exiting...'
  , Exit   = 'Exiting...'
}
local input
print 'Type a Number!'
repeat
    input = io.read ()
    print (inputs [input] or 'incorrect') -- Lua 'nullsafe' operator.
until input == 'Exit' or input == 'exit'
```